# Sharepoint 2013 minimum hardware requirement - minimum core processor

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, configuration

I want to buy a new laptop with the purpose to develop application in SP2013 and create a test environment if possible (more than a single layer).

But I noticed that the minimum requirement to use it are 4 cores processor.
(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485%28office.15%29.aspx)

And I have found a **DELL** **i7-4510U 2.00/3.10** - it means, 2 core processor.
The seller told me that they are building laptops with less cores nowadays to save battery.
But the rest of the configuration of the laptop is fine, **8GB RAM** (I will put more 8GB).
**500 GB of SSD memory** (I saw somewhere else that it can compensate the less 2 core from the processor).

I would like to know if these requirements are really strict ? If I have a 2 core processor with all this configuration Sharepoint 2013 would run nicely ?

Comment: Cannot find anything on such Intel CPU. do you mean i7-4510U perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, edited now. i7-4510U ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean i7-4510U, you'll be fine. It's got 2 cores, but each with 4 threads. 16 GB RAM is more important, and with SSD SP2013 will fly.

Comment: I hope you are right, do you think that I will get alerts from the central administration or will have some problems when it will install (does it check the #cores before installation ?). Your comment made my day :)

Comment: I have SharePoint installed on 2 core CPU just fine (if slowwwwwwwwllllllllyyyyyyyy). Alerts are just notifications.

Comment: Installation does not check for cores. I've personally ran SP2013 on VMware virtual machine on Dell Latitude E6420 with SSD, 16GB RAM, i5 CPU (can't remember which exactly) that had 2 cores, and I didn't feel performance being any kind of issue. Only due to many different projects, I needed several VMs, so SSD space became a limitation and I moved everything to Azure VMs.

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint will run but you will get slowness. Some services, such as search, may not work.

In the central administration you will have alerts on performance.

But for development will probably meet the needs

Answer (score 0):

I'm using dual core E5550 + 8GB RAM to host SharePoint 2013, SQL Server 2014, Visual Studio 2013 (community).

However this CPU should be stronger then any that can be found in notebook!

Its doable, but slow. Especially accessing SharePoint via browser, takes minutes.

Go for 4 physical cores (i5 or better), and think about putting more RAM - must be dual channel, and that mean 2 RAM chips of exact specs - there too! (My server is constantly at 7,8 GB of ram taken and const memory swapping)

However if You will develop JUST sharepoint apps (and not .wsp solutions!) then local Sharepoint (and SQL) is not needed, and maybe You can just rent some Azure server for testing purposes. VS will happily work with remote server for apps (but not for .wsp!).

Then just make sure You buy i5 or better, and it should work.

PS Are You sure that its SSD? 500GB SSD is quite expensive, so I would expect to see 4 core CPU as well there and some good RAM too. Maybe its hybrid "SSHD"? .wsp solutions DO like fast disks.

Comment: This SSD is not that needed, I just tough that adding it would open the applications quicker. The problem is that, as far as I heard, usually the laptops are trying to save battery, and when I ask for a 4 cores + 8 GB, but can be expandable to 16 GB, the price increases a lot.